# How to invalidate cache on mmap'ed shared memory (multi processor machine)

Tags: c, linux, caching, mmap, smp

I have two processes, sharing a memory area for fast communication. Both processes run the following (error check removed):

```
int fd = open("/run/afile", O_RDWR );
void *ptr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
volatile struct data *shared_data = (struct data *) ptr;
```

The mmap is backed by the previously created file /run/afile, ( /run is mounted as tempfs, I am assuming 'afile' lives in RAM)

Process A writes data like this:

```
data->field1 = 34;
data->field2 = 231;
data->new_data_flag = 1;
```

Process B, at certain points, checks for `data->new_data_flag`, and then reads `data->field1` and `data->field2`

The question is, how can I force the shared memory area to be updated so the changes are visible for Process B?

I understand `msync()` will update `/run/afile`; is this automatically invalidating Process B cache on its own mapping of `/run/afile`?

Side question: I am using `volatile` on `struct data` to prevent the compiler from reordering the writes into `field1`, `field2` and `new_data_flag`. Is this correct?